# Remove all vowels of a string with recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I can remove the vowels without a recursive function like this:

```
NoVowels:: String -> String
NoVowels xs = filter f xs where f x = not (x == ’a’ || x == ’e’ || x == ’i’ || x == ’o’ || x == ’u’)
```

But how may I do that with a recursive function ?

I tried something like this but of course did not work (parse Error):

```
NoVowels :: String -> String
NoVowels "" = error "Empty String!!"
NoVowels (x:xs)
   | x in (x == 'a'|| x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u') = NoVowels (tail x)
```

If the `head` is a vowel then I CUT it from the string and pass recursively the `tail`, if its not a vowel how may I verify the other string without removing it.

*Update obs:* I want to return the function without the vowels.

Comment: `x` is the head of the list. You can't find the head of the tail of the list. You would use `xs` instead of `tail x`

Comment: There is no reason to create an error for the empty string. Indeed, it will break your recursion.

Comment: You shouldn't have `in` in a guard syntax.

Comment: @PyRulez I cant find document explaining the use of `In` `where`. could you give me a quick explanation ?

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where
and
http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thins it makes sense to define a function `isVowel :: Char->Bool` and after that write something like this :

```
noVowels :: String -> String
noVowels [] = []
noVowels (x:xs)
   |isVowel x = noVowels xs
   |otherwise = x : noVowels xs
```

If you don't want to define one more function you can try next code :

```
noVowels :: String ->String
noVowels [] = []
noVowels (x:xs)
  |not( x `elem` "aeiou") = x: noVowels xs
  |otherwise = noVowels xs
```

Comment: I need to return the string without the vowels. Sorry I had to mention that.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro then define function isNotVowel. Code will remain the same

Comment: This code will not work. You are returning an error for your base case.

Comment: >Not in scope: `isVowel'

Comment: NO way to check the vowel without `isVowel´ high ordern function ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro You could, it is just simpler this way. Indeed, what is later you want to filter a `Set Char` for vowels, or a `Map k Char` or `Map Char v`. This way, you can reuse the `isVowel` and/or `noVowel` function.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro yes, I edited the answer to provide a version without creating new function

Comment: @ig-melnyk perfect ! Thank you man ! Could you explain me the `x: noVowels xs`

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro you are welcome. ":"operator adds element to the list. 
For example, 1:[2,3] == [1,2,3].
So we are adding element x to the list recursively creating list noVowels

Comment: You rock. Thanks again !

Comment: Just to note, this won't work with uppercase vowels. You needed to add "AEIOU" to the string pattern

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of an improvement on the code. Just in case you missed out on preserving the cases involved.

```
module Disemvowel where

disemvowel :: String -> String
disemvowel []  = []
disemvowel " " = " "
disemvowel (x:xs)
                | x `elem` "aeiouAEIOU" = disemvowel xs
                | otherwise = [x] ++ disemvowel xs
```